# How start server Django in the VM (Vagrant)

Tags: python, django, vagrant

i want install Django in my VM created with PuPHPpet (Vagrant), then when i start the server with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

My project is normally available in 127.0.0.1:8000
But i have unreachable web page, then i try

```
python manage.py runserver ipvm:8000 and others ports
```

I have always unreachable web page
So, i have found in this forum

```
0.0.0.0:8000
```

And i have again unreachable web page, Why ? How can start my server in my VM ?

Answer (score 11):

You have to forward the port from Vagrant to your local machine. You can add a line like this to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8001, guest: 8000
```

And then run this in the Vagrant VM:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And on your host machine, go to http://localhost:8001 to view the webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my vagrant file i have a variables, then, i try to add forwarded port via PuPHPpet and i try localhost;8001 and i have  unreachable web page

Answer (score 0):

Run python manage.py runserver 0:8000. It worked for me

Comment: Hi Sachin, welcome to SO! This answer appears to be very similar to the answer that was already accepted. Might it be a duplicate?

Comment: A lot of confusion about the solution that's I thought of posting it. Never intended for duplicate content

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to forward the port from Vagrant to your local machine.

   config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8001, guest: 8000
2. Yo need to add IP to ALLOWED_HOST in your setting.py file

   0.0.0.0 to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings.py
3. Run Project

   python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000